# Drupal 7 Homebox module and Twitter Bootstrap theme

Tags: 7, theming, dashboard

I am using Drupal Homebox module (https://drupal.org/project/homebox, version 7.x-2.0-beta6) to create a dashboard. I've found an issue that the save function to keep the status/location of blocks on the dashboard (closing or moving) doesn't work when using Twitter bootstrap theme. But there is no problem when using Batik theme. I could not find any clues of what cause this issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Hi make this change found on sites/all/modules/homebox/hombox.js on line 16.

```
Drupal.homebox.$pageSave = $homebox.find('#homebox-save-form button[type=submit]');
```

*Why?*
bootstrap changes the input type in the page.tpl so you need to reflect the changed